# Scanning through a tilemap and checking properties for each tile

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tiles

How does one iterate through a tilemap and check each tile?

Is there a correct way to do this, is there a  built in function to in cocos2d to check a tile?

Or could it be done e.g. take the tile size set when creating the tile, make a nested for loop and take (x,y) for the middle of the first tile and just iterate by adding tilesize to the x on the inner loop and tilesize to the y on the outer loop?

I am wondering if there is a built in, more performance aware approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to do it using a for loop and CGPoints.
I'm going to for examples sake get color
and store it in an array I guess

```
CGPoint myPt;
NSMutableArray *tilesofGray;

for (int x = 0; x < tilemapLength)
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < tilemapHeight)
            {
                myPt.x = x;
                myPt.y = y;

                if([[[tilemap layerNamed:@"background"] tileAt:myPt] getColor] == Grey)
                {
                    [tilesofGray addObject:[[tilemap layerNamed:@"background] tileAt:myPt]];
                 }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this for a game, for like collision detection or, simply for rendering based on tile type?

Your question here is really ambiguous. Please be specific in what you want. The 3rd sentence in particular would make more sense if you explain what you are needing.

But i'll try to answer based on the title alone....

- How big is the tileset? if it's not very big, brute-force may be perfectly fine.
- If performance is a concern/issue, or if the tileset is large and not all tiles are ever drawn within the screen at any given time, you need to do scene management of some sort.

scene management:
i think there is a technical term/phrase for this, but basically based on some x,y pt on the tileset (i.e. matrix), you can determine (by a function) which tiles you will need to iterate thru. it should be fun to figure it out as it's presumably a 2d array.

Comment: This is for a game. The tileset is around 320x2040(tile size is 20x20). So it isnt that large. You never answered my question about how to iterate and get the tile properties(using a built in function call in the iteration) not what to iterate on. :) I would like to know if there is some kind of cocos2d function to check each tiles properties or if I should code my own.

Comment: Typemiss? Shouldn't that be 320x240?

Comment: ok i guess i dont understand your situation. why would cocoa know anything about your tiles? im guessing you are speaking of some standard cocoa-related "tile" that im not familiar with.

Comment: you want to check all tile properties for what purpose?

Comment: I tagged the question with Cocos2d.